# Event Listener in JavaScript not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('ul.mylist').on('click', 'li', function(){})
```

I want to transform this jQuery line into vanilla but how I can do this ? I looked at jQuery source but I'm confused. Is there simple way to do this in pure Javascript ?

Comment: Yes, though whether or not it would still be considered "simple" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Also, the code gets considerably more complex the more browsers you want to support.

Comment: Why do you need this? The delegation, filtering, tagname.classname selector makes this hard to duplicate with just a few lines, and there's probably need for some recursion to check for closest LI to event.target etc.

Comment: Why down vote this question? sounds fair enough to me. Difficult to answer doesn't mean its a wrong question.. looking at the popularity of new framework, lots of new beginners learn these by default.. and these questions might come up..

Comment: @Shaunak seems to match the description on the downvote button. `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful` the first part in particular.

Comment: I didn't down vote it, but it was probably down voted because the OP showed no effort or what was tried to solve it.

Comment: for example...its how we assume something like C++ is the way to do things, but of-course it can be written in assembly language.. and can be mysterious to the beginners to the extent that they don't even know right keywords to start searching for it.. Still think it doesn't deserve a down vote.. may be a 'let me google that for you' :)

Comment: I'm just curious. It doesn't have to be this specific example. But I would like to know how  can I JS attach event listener to some parent element and listen for events on it's childs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some features here are browser dependent, but this is basically how it goes...

```
// select all UL elements with the `mylist` class
var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul.mylist');

// Iterate the collection, and bind the `click` handler
for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++)
    uls[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);

// The `click` handler iterates starting with `event.target` through its
//   ancestors until the bound element is found. Each element matching the
//   "LI" nodeName will run your code.
function handler(event) {
    var node = event.target;
    do {
        if (node.nodeName === "LI") {
            // RUN YOUR CODE HERE
        }
    } while (node !== this && (node = node.parentNode));
}
```

You can make the selector test more broad by using `node.matchesSelector(".my.selector")`, though that method is implemented using browser-specific property flags in some browsers, so you'd need to first expose it on the `Element.prototype` under the proper name.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click listener to any element as follows:

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li> item 1</li>
<li> item 2</li>
<li> item 3</li>
<li> item 4</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function click_handler(){
    alert('you clicked a list');
}
var list=document.getElementById("mylist");
list.onclick=click_handler;

</script>
```

here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FB3q/)